# Desired fields did get create after modifying logstash config

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, grok

I have created two different elastic search clusters.

In first cluster (created newly) ,(v 7.13.2), I have created below config in pipeline.conf under conf.d for logstash and it worked as I see expected fields getting created in index. I verified this from Stack Management --> Index Management --> there is only one index (as data is not getting generated regularly) ---> after clicking on it, in Mappings tab.

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})\| %{USERNAME:exchangeId}\| %{DATA:trackingId}\| %{NUMBER:RoundTrip:int}%{SPACE}ms\| %{NUMBER:ProxyRoundTrip:int}%{SPACE}ms\| %{NUMBER:UserInfoRoundTrip:int}%{SPACE}ms\| %{DATA:Resource}\| %{DATA:subject}\| %{DATA:authmech}\| %{DATA:scopes}\| %{IPV4:Client}\| %{WORD:method}\| %{DATA:Request_URI}\| %{INT:response_code}\| %{DATA:failedRuleType}\| %{DATA:failedRuleName}\| %{DATA:APP_Name}\| %{DATA:Resource_Name}\| %{DATA:Path_Prefix}"} 
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    }
}
```

The second cluster (7.4.0) which was already running, It had below config in

```
if [log_type] == "access_server" and [app_id] == "as"
  {
    mutate { gsub => ["message","\|"," "] } grok { patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/patterns"] match => { "message" => "%{MY_DATE_PATTERN:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}%{UUID:ConsentID}%{SPACE}%{WORD:TransactionID}%{SPACE}%{WORD:TraceID}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:messagetext}" } }
    mutate {
             replace => {
               "[type]" => "access_server"
             }
           }
  }

output {
if [log_type] == "access_server" {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ['http://14.1.1.50:9200']
    index => "%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        user => elastic
    password => NfBxxxxx
      }
 }

elasticsearch {
    hosts => ['http://14.1.1.50:9200']
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    user => elastic
    password => NfBxxxxx
  }
}
```

I modified the config file yesterday (06-July-21) to below to have individual fields as per desired data types, (as per the above first cluster config)

```
if [log_type] == "access_server" and [app_id] == "as"
  {
    mutate { gsub => ["message","\|"," "] } grok { patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/patterns"] match => { "message" => "%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})\| %{USERNAME:exchangeId}\| %{DATA:trackingId}\| %{NUMBER:RoundTrip:int}%{SPACE}ms\| %{NUMBER:ProxyRoundTrip:int}%{SPACE}ms\| %{NUMBER:UserInfoRoundTrip:int}%{SPACE}ms\| %{DATA:Resource}\| %{DATA:subject}\| %{DATA:authmech}\| %{DATA:scopes}\| %{IPV4:Client}\| %{WORD:method}\| %{DATA:Request_URI}\| %{INT:response_code}\| %{DATA:failedRuleType}\| %{DATA:failedRuleName}\| %{DATA:APP_Name}\| %{DATA:Resource_Name}\| %{DATA:Path_Prefix}" } }
    mutate {
             replace => {
               "[type]" => "access_server"
             }
           }
  }

output {

  if [log_type] == "access_server" {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ['http://14.1.1.50:9200']
    index => "%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        user => elastic
    password => NfBxxxxxx
      }
 }

elasticsearch {
    hosts => ['http://14.1.1.50:9200']
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    user => elastic
    password => NfBxxxxxx
  }
```

and restarted logstash but today's access_server index is not having above individual fields.

The difference between above two clusters is, first cluster which I created to test above scenario (v 7.13.2), is having only one index (it indexed old log files and there are no new log files getting created daily), and I have created Index pattern of it in kibana but in second cluster which was already running is having daily indices of access_server but I have not created index patterns of it so I looked into today's access_server index but it is not having desired individual fields but I think the main issue is because of configration in pipeline.conf file which I mentioned above.

Can you please let me know what is not correct in modified pipeline.conf file because of which I still can't see individual message fields in today's index.

Comment: Hi, Can someone please reply.

Comment: can you post a line of your `access_server` log file for someone to actually test it and see?

Comment: @JBone, Sorry fore late reply.  here is the line                                                    
 ```2021-06-26T04:50:10,467| YerhHTEWoROUdQ| | 6 ms| 3 ms| 0 ms| devel.dev.next2.only.io [] / /*:443| | | | 152.49.95.120| GET| /component---src-pages-products-isp-js-780354591ab39a6d4f3.js| 200| | | Dev SPA| Root Resource| /*```

Comment: got the results as per below

Answer (score 0):

able to get the desired result by adding below in `logstash.conf`,

```
if [log_type] == "access_server" and [app_id] == "as"
  {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})\| %{USERNAME:exchangeId}\| %{DATA:trackingId}\| %{NUMBER:RoundTrip:int}%{SPACE}ms\| %{NUMBER:ProxyRoundTrip:int}%{SPACE}ms\| %{NUMBER:UserInfoRoundTrip:int}%{SPACE}ms\| %{DATA:Resource}\| %{DATA:subject}\| %{DATA:authmech}\| %{DATA:scopes}\| %{IPV4:Client}\| %{WORD:method}\| %{DATA:Request_URI}\| %{INT:response_code}\| %{DATA:failedRuleType}\| %{DATA:failedRuleName}\| %{DATA:APP_Name}\| %{DATA:Resource_Name}\| %{DATA:Path_Prefix}" } }
    mutate {
             replace => {
               "[type]" => "access_server"
             }
           } 
  }
```